# A TikZ picture-within-a-picture inside a Hebrew document causes lualatex to fail when the language manager is babel, but not when it is polyglossia

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, polyglossia, hebrew

The following LaTeX code was saved in `~/test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\iffalse
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{FreeSans}
\fi

\iffalse
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[main,import]{hebrew}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSans}
\fi

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\squarecmd}{ \pic {square}; }
\tikzset{
   square/.pic={ \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1); },
   picture/.pic={ \squarecmd; }
}
\begin{document}

\tikz \pic{picture};

\end{document}
```

Then the following command was executed in the Terminal: `lualatex ~/test`. Consequently, the file `~/test.pdf` was created. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed as follows. (The page number in the bottom of the page was clipped out of the screenshot.)

[image: A square]

The `polyglossia` chunk was then made active by commenting the two lines surrounding it  containing `\iffalse` and `\fi`, and `lualatex ~/test` was rerun. The compilation ended successfully, and a file was created at `~/test.pdf`, which, when opened in a PDF viewer, displayed as follows. (The page number in the bottom of the page was again clipped out of the screenshot.)

[image: The same square, with Hebrew as the main language, via polyglossia.]

Note that, since Hebrew is a right-to-left language, the changed location of the square is correct.

I now restored the `polyglossia` chunk to its previous dormant state, and instead made the `babel` chunk active. When I now executed `lualatex ~/test`, the compilation failed, and `~/test.log` contained the following snippet.

```
warning  (hpack filter): error: ...e/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel-bid
i-basic.lua:345: attempt to index a nil value (field '?')

.
\tikz@subpicture@handle@ ...tpath \egroup \egroup 
                                                  \egroup \fi \pgfkeysgetval...
l.25 \tikz \pic{picture}
                      ;
? 
! Emergency stop.
\tikz@subpicture@handle@ ...tpath \egroup \egroup 
                                                  \egroup \fi \pgfkeysgetval...
l.25 \tikz \pic{picture}
                      ;
End of file on the terminal!
```

Why did the `babel` package produce an error? How can this be fixed so that the compilation is successful, and the resulting PDF file displays the same as when the `polyglossia` package is active?

Note that one way to fix the problem is by replacing the call to the `\squarecmd` command by its body. But this fix is to be avoided. The above example is a watered-down version of the situation I am dealing with in my actual document, and in that document the command takes arguments, so it cannot be readily substituted by its body.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. The output compiled with LuaLaTeX (TeX Live 2022) is the same for me with `polyglossia` and with `babel`.

Comment: I can't reproduce either (on Overleaf), however the `;` after `\squarecmd` is superfluous. It shouldn't break anything, though.

Comment: remove the semicolon after your command.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I get reproducibly an error if there is a semicolon too much.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I've deleted my previous comment. I retested everything, and it works as described in my post. I too use Tex Live 2022.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. But I feel the semicolon shouldn't have caused an issue. Is this a bug in `babel`? If so, I will report it.

Comment: I will report it, but nevertheless your code is faulty, even with pdflatex you would produce a `Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!`.

Comment: added an issue: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/197

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. So the problem is that there cannot be two consecutive semicolons inside the body of a TikZ `/.pic`. Indeed, I was able to reproduce the problem by replacing the body of the `\tikzset` by `\tikzset{ picture/.pic={ \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);; } }`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Strange, I tested TeX Live 2022 on Overleaf and got not error. Does this version differ from the most recent LuaLaTeX version?

Comment: @JasperHabicht yes, overleaf lags behind. It certainly has an older babel (and bidi is in development), older latex, and probably also older luaotfload.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, that explains a lot. I re-tried with my local installation and indeed got the above error. I did not notice, since the version number of LuaHBTeX is the same. Sorry for any confusion!